# How to get values from android on PHP server

Tags: java, php, android, http, httpclient

```
public void postData() {  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/howdy/welcome.php");  

        try {  

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "rxn"));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "b15803"));  
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request  
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  
            System.out.println("data posted, status = " + status);  

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        } 





    }
```

Here is my code to post name and id to my local server. now what will be the php code to accept these arguments so that i can able to store in a variable and echo on web page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending this data as a `POST` request, so on the other side simply get it using the `$_POST` variable. This would be an example:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo "Hi, my name is $name and my id is $id\n";
```